# Handling a list of files and directories with spaces in an array

Tags: macos, bash

How do I best handle a mix of files and directories in an array. I need to create an array of files and folders and loop through the array and subject each item in the array to the rm command with the -rf options:

```
#Build array of files to be deleted

FILES=(
"~/Library/Preferences/Adobe InDesign"
"~/Library/Caches/Adobe InDesign"
"~/Library/Saved Application State/com.adobe.InDesign.savedstate"
)


#Loop through array deleting each file/directory with the recursive force options

    for i in "${FILES[@]}"

      do

        rm -rf "$i"

      done

    exit
```

Comment: using the shell "debugger" `set -vx` will show you how your command is being processed. I bet you don't want dbl-quotes around `${FILES[@]}`. Good luck.

Comment: actually this code should work, any errors you get from it?

Comment: @mpapis it executes with no error. I used shellter's approach with debugging...it isn't doing anything funny with parsing the whitespace in the variable names...but it does not delete the files? I feel like i'm losing my mind.

Comment: verified permissions as well, even created a new folder called "test" and a new file "testfile" and it won't delete them either.

Comment: turn off debugging temporarily, add `echo ` in front of `rm` and edit your post with the output? Loosing your mind, that's not good. Oh hey, I had a crazy spot yesterday, I had imported a shell script with \r\n (DOS) line endings and `vim` didn't show the `^M` that I would expected AND the results were completely mystifying. `cat -vet myScript` to eliminate this possibility. Good luck.

Comment: The result of substituting echo is `
~/Library/Application Support/Test
`

Comment: @shellter The result of substituting echo is `~/Library/Application Support/Test` so that is what I presume gets passed to rm -rf...which would break at the whitespace. But I have also used a \ in the array declaration - which when echo'd appears correctly but the result is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't with the array or spaces, it's with the `~` in the file paths. `~` isn't really a valid part of a path, but the shell will replace replace it with your home directory's path ... unless it's in quotes:

```
$ echo ~/Library/Preferences/Adobe InDesign
/Users/gordon/Library/Preferences/Adobe InDesign
$ echo "~/Library/Preferences/Adobe InDesign"
~/Library/Preferences/Adobe InDesign
```

So you can either put the `~` outside the quotes:

```
FILES=(
~/"Library/Preferences/Adobe InDesign"
~/"Library/Caches/Adobe InDesign"
~/"Library/Saved Application State/com.adobe.InDesign.savedstate"
)
```

Or use $HOME (which does get substituted in double-quotes):

```
FILES=(
"$HOME/Library/Preferences/Adobe InDesign"
"$HOME/Library/Caches/Adobe InDesign"
"$HOME/Library/Saved Application State/com.adobe.InDesign.savedstate"
)
```

Comment: Can't believe I didn't realize that the shell wasn't expanding ~ because it was quoted. Thank you for catching this. Excellent explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this trick sometimes:

```
with_expanded_paths()
{
  typeset IFS
  IFS=""
  "$@"
}
with_expanded_paths rm -rf "~/file with spaces"
```

I wrote it from memory so slight adjustments might be needed.